# Animate framemodule back()

Tags: nativescript

`frameModule.topmost().goBack()`

When I call above, the page switches right away w/o animation.

Anyway to get it to slide or something?

Answer (score 0):

There is `animated` in NativeScript Frame module API:

```
frameModule.topmost().animated = true;
```

http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_frame_.frame.html#animated

Comment: Is this a global flag? I tried it and set it the the navigatingTo of the main page - no noticable changes when transiting to other pages or back.

Comment: I set it in `loaded()` and I think it's not global

Comment: I had to set the transition in the object passed to frame.navigate(). That worked! I didn't have to set the frameModule.topmost().animated to true - it's enabled by default.